# Using a Pipe to Write and Read Array of Int

Tags: c, arrays, pipe, fork

I'm trying to make a simple program using the pipe. The program must request an array of integers in the parent, and send it to the child, which must sort the array and send it back to the parent.
The problem is that I'm not sure how I read the array values in the child, after sending through the pipe.

follow my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {

int fd[2];
pid_t pid;

/* Verifica se ocorreu erro (-1) ao criar o PIPE */
if(pipe(fd) == -1){
    perror("pipe");
    exit(1);
}

/* Verifica se o fork foi realizado com sucesso > 0 */
if((pid = fork()) < 0){
    perror("fork");
    exit(1);
}

if(pid > 0){

    printf("-----------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("                PROCESSO PAI                   \n");
    printf("-----------------------------------------------\n");

    /* Como vamos ESCREVER do lado do PAI, fechamos a LEITURA */
    close(fd[0]);

    int numeros[5];

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        printf("\nDigite o numero [%d]: ", i);
        scanf("%d", &numeros[i]);
    }

    /* Escrevendo o array no PIPE */
    write(fd[1], numeros, sizeof(numeros) + 1);
    printf("\nEnviando numeros para meu Filho...\n");
    exit(0);

}else{

    int numeros_recebidos[5];

    /* Como vamos LER do lado do FILHO, fechamos a ESCRITA*/
    close(fd[1]);

    /* Lendo a mensagem que foi enviada pelo FILHO */
    read(fd[0], numeros_recebidos, sizeof(numeros_recebidos));
    printf("\n-----------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("                PROCESSO FILHO                 \n");
    printf("-----------------------------------------------\n");

    printf("\nNumeros Recebidos, Ordenando...\n");


    for(int i = 0; i<5; i++){
        printf("%d \n", &numeros_recebidos[i]);
    }
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need two pipes, one for the parent to send data to the child and one for the child to send data to the parent.  Anything else is unreliable; the parent might end up reading data that it wrote.  At best, you'd have to have a protocol such as 'send the number of integers to read and the data to the child; sleep for a second; then read the response from the child'.  Even that's not formally guaranteed; scheduling of processes is unpredictable and the child might not get scheduled for a whole second if the system is unbearably busy (but it is extremely unlikely to be a problem).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

your program is working fine except few bugs like

```
 for(int i = 0; i<5; i++){
        printf("%d \n", &numeros_recebidos[i]); // why &, remove it bcz you are printing data not scanning.
```

**How child and parent are communicating through pipe** :

There are some important things about pipe() :

1)`pipe()` system call will create two ends called `fd[0]` and `fd1[1`]. one is reserved for `reading` purpose and another is reserved for `writing` purpose.

2)`pipe` is a `uni-directional IPC` i.e at a time you can only read or write from/to one end of pipe, both not possible simultaneously.

3)only **related process** (like child & parent ) can communicate through `pipe()`.

**parent process** : parent process is writing array of integers into `fd[1]`. once it'd done now data is there in writing end of `pipe()`.  Next thing is child job's to read data from here so let's jump to child process.

```
                            pipe(uni-directional)
                       |---------------------------| 
parent is writing----->|                           |<---------
                       |---------------------------| 
                     fd[1]                        fd[0]

        write(fd[1], numeros, sizeof(numeros) + 1);
```

`child process` : parent has putted int array into fd[1] now child has to read from fd[0] and prints it.

```
          pipe(uni-directional)
      |---------------------------| 
----->|                           |<-----child process is reading data & storing in numeros_recebidos
      |---------------------------| 
     fd[1]                       fd[0]

  read(fd[0], numeros_recebidos, sizeof(numeros_recebidos));
```

I hope it helps to understand pipe() working.

Comment: When using pipes, it is very important to close unused ends of pipes to ensure that EOF conditions are detected when you expect them.  If any process has the writing end of a pipe open, no reading process will detect EOF on the reading end of the pipe, even if the only such process is the reading process, and it will hang indefinitely in a read waiting for a write that will never happen. Also, the 0 element of the pair of file descriptors is the reading end (0 = standard input) and should never be written to; the 1 element is the writing end (1 = standard output) and should never be read from.