# Child process not reading correct values from pipe

Tags: c, arrays, pipe, fork

I have two processes:

**Master.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

void error(char *m)
{
    write(2, m, strlen(m));
    write(2, "\n", 1);
    write(2, strerror(errno), strlen(strerror(errno))); exit(1);

}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   int fd1[2],fd2[0];
int numeros[1000];
int val;
int wpid;
int status = 0;

signal(SIGINT, sigint_handler);

if (pipe(fd1) < 0) error("Pipe creation");

pid1 = fork();

switch (pid1) {
        case -1: error("Fork 1");
        case 0: /* Procés fill */
              close(0);
              dup(fd1[0]);
              close(fd1[1]);
              execv("./Second",NULL);

        default: /* Procés pare */
            break;
}

close(1);
dup(fd1[1]);
close(fd1[0]);

for( val = 0; val <= 1000; val++)
     numeros[val]=val;


write(1, numeros, sizeof(numeros)+1);

while ((wpid = wait(&status)) > 0);

exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);

return 0;
}
```

**Second:**

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i,k = 0;
    int num_rev[1000];
    int num_pair[1000];

    read(0, num_rev, sizeof(num_rev));

    for( i = 1; i <= 1000; i++){
        int temp = num_rev[i];
        printf("Child(%d) received value: %d\n", getpid(), temp);
        int m = temp % 2;
        if (m != 0){
            num_pair[k]=temp;
            printf("Second filtered value: %d\n", temp);
            k++;
        }
    }

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);

    return 0;
}
```

First as parent, creates Second as child and sends integers values from 1 to 1000 in a array, using a pipe, redirecting stdout and stdin. I have followed this post as example:

[Using a Pipe to Write and Read Array of Int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47371735/using-a-pipe-to-write-and-read-array-of-int)

but Second process is receiving unexpected values:

```
Child(2370) received value: 32766
Child(2370) received value: 6
Child(2370) received value: 0
Child(2370) received value: 14
Child(2370) received value: 0
Child(2370) received value: 354020744
Child(2370) received value: 1
```

Thanks.

Comment: Several issues: 1. Your `error` function in the parent will overwrite `errno` before printing it. 2. Your loops use `<=` as the looping condition, meaning they try to set element 1000 of the array, which is UB because the maximum index is 999 (for 1000 total values in the arrays). 3. (this is *probably* where you’re seeing the issues, but I’m not sure) You’re calling `read` once in the child process, but you don’t verify that everything was read. *Always, **always*** check the return value of `read` even if you ignore it for other system calls.

Comment: The `error` function _might_ overwrite `errno`; it is not guaranteed to do so.  The `write(1, numeros, sizeof(numeros)+1);` is weird; it writes one byte more than there is space in the `numeros` array, which is undefined behaviour.  It isn't clear why you think the extra byte might be helpful.  You should also error check any open-like calls (as well as any input calls — like `read()`).

Comment: **Rule of thumb**: If you
[`dup2()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dup2.html)
one end of a pipe to standard input or standard output, close both ends
of the pipe as soon as possible.
That means before using any of the
[`exec*()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/execvp.html)
family of functions in particular.

It also includes using
[`dup()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dup.html)
or
[`fcntl()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fcntl.html)
with `F_DUPFD`.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. After checking the read return value, it gives me a bad file descriptor error. I'm trying to figure out why.